# How to prove that if a linear transformation $T \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is invertible, then $n = m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

How do you prove that if  a linear map  $T : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is invertible then $n=m$ using the Rank Nullity Theorem and using the fact that an invertible function has to be both surjective and injective?

Comment: What does Rank-Nullity say in this case?

Comment: It says that for any  _n x m_ matrix, dim (ker(A)) + dim (Im(A)) = _m_

Comment: As a stepping stone try and prove the following: $T$ is invertible if and only if $T$ is injective and surjective. Then applying the Rank-nullity result, as T.Gunn suggets.

Comment: @N.Babuchak you should note that your formulation of the rank nullity theorem identifies $T$ with a matrix $A$. Restate the RN-theorem in terms of the linear transformation $T$ of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is surjective so $\dim \operatorname{im}T = n$. $T$ is injective, so $\dim \ker T = 0$. By rank nullity we have $$\dim \ker T + \dim \operatorname{im} T = \dim \mathbb{R}^m \iff n=m$$

Comment: sorry could you also explain why injectivity means that dim ker _T_ = 0

Comment: @N.Babuchak assume that $\dim \ker T \neq 0$. Then you have at least two elements in $\ker T$, both are sent to the same thing (the identity). i.e $T(a) = e$ and $T(b) = e$ for distinct $a,b \in \ker T$. But injectivity states that $T(a) = T(b) \implies a=b$. So $\dim \ker T \neq 0 \implies T$ not injective. Hence $T$ injective implies $\dim \ker T = 0$.

Comment: @N.Babuchak alternatively note that  if $T(a) = T(b) \implies a=b$ then $T(0) = 0$ so if  $T(a) = 0$ so i.e $a \in \ker T$ then by injectivity $a=0$. So $\ker T=\{0\}$ and $\dim \ker T = 0$ as it is a single point.